# Codeigniter 2.1 switch_uri() and i18n language library

Tags: codeigniter, internationalization

I'm building my application with Codeigniter 2.1 and I'm using i18n multilanguage library and everything works fine. The only problem comes when I translate the current page, it's ok, but when I change the page, it returns it in default language. Example:

> myapp.com/en/home
>
> click on anchor(switch_uri('de'))
>
> myapp.com/de/home
>
> now follow link to another controller and it comes back to the default
>   language
>
> myapp.com/en/about

So how can I fix it and when I switch the controller, the language stays the last chosen, not the default one?

Thanks in advance. :)

EDIT:

These are my anchors to change page language. I think I may use some kind of cookie to save the user's language and get it on every next controller load, but I'm sure there is something more simply and easy.

```
<ul id="languages">
    <li><a href="<?= base_url($this->lang->switch_uri('bg')) ?>" class="lang-bg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="<?= base_url($this->lang->switch_uri('en')) ?>" class="lang-en"></a></li>
</ul>
```

There are my links to other pages in the main menu:

```
<li>
    <?= anchor(base_url('about'), 'about') ?>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you have the links?

Comment: I edited my question above. :)

Comment: No I meant the links for the controllers. If you have implemented correctly it should not be a problem they should work and the language should not change. I asked for the links to see if you have the languages hardcoded in there (controller/function/en) if you hard coded the languages in links like this then you should remove the language parameter at the end.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't understand. But as you can see above after my last edit, the language isn't fixed in links. So the problem is somewhere else I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok as I can see the problem is in the link where you are using base_url(). Try the links like this without the base_url().

```
<?php echo anchor('about/index/', 'About'); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I really didn't know that base_url() could cause the problem. You saved my life. Thanks again! :)

Comment: I have exactly same problem I do not use `base_url` `anchor('auth/logout', 'logout')` and after language change (I change languages trhru links eg `localhost/project/en` or `localhost/project/fr` (after clicking the 2nd link is language changed? or what do I have to do in order to change language?

Comment: @Kyslik I am not using codeigniter anymore but last time I used i18n library, I used this one [here](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/CodeIgniter-2.1-internationalization-i18n). Check that and see if it helps you.

Comment: Yes I am using the very same one. :)

Comment: @Kyslik If you've set it up correctly to change the language you create an anchor as stated at the end of the guide `anchor($this->lang->switch_uri('fr'),'Display current page in French');` This code will create a link that will change the language (in this case french).

Comment: I know that way but `switch_uri` throws me error :/ (undefined return value) I checked code, and it is  suppose to return `$uri` variable, but if/else statement does not "click" so it is undefined. It is problem with `$URI->uri_string();` or something. I'll probably post a new question on this. Thanks for effor tho :).

Comment: @Kyslik yeah it would be better to post a question with the code, I can't really understand from the comments what's going on, sorry.